# how to left join the relation to join five latest rows only

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i am joining the latest relation row with the following code.

```
SELECT pos.* FROM users AS usr LEFT JOIN posts AS pos ON pos.user_id = usr.id WHERE
                                pos.id = (
                                    SELECT MAX(id)
                                    FROM posts
                                    WHERE user_id = usr.id
                                );
```

if I want to join the second last row only here is the code

```
SELECT pos.* FROM users AS usr LEFT JOIN posts AS pos ON pos.user_id = usr.id WHERE
                                pos.id = (
                                    SELECT id
                                    FROM posts
                                    WHERE user_id = usr.id
                                    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1
                                );
```

The question is what i can do  if I want to join the latest five rows again in each relation?

Comment: The standard solution is to use a lateral join.

Comment: Please include a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Also, lateral joins are only supported in newer versions of MySQL. Please indicate the exact MySQL version you are using (run `select version();`).

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7.37